# How i do correct while loop, which read two files

Tags: linux, shell

I have tried to do `.sh` script which read two file. Currently i got this error `line 7: file1: No such file or directory`

user & city files are in same folder as script.

```
#!/bin/bash
file1='user.txt'
file2='city.txt'

while read -r -u 4 line1 && read -r -u 5 line2; do
  echo "Output-1: $line1 & Output-2: $line2"
done 4<file1 5<file2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is trying to tell you that there is no such file named "file1":

> file1: No such file or directory

It's not "file1" you want to read input from, but "user.txt",
which is in the value of the variable `file1`.
To do that, write `$file1` instead of `file1`, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
file1='user.txt'
file2='city.txt'

while read -r -u 4 line1 && read -r -u 5 line2; do
  echo "Output-1: $line1 & Output-2: $line2"
done 4<"$file1" 5<"$file2"
```

Comment: Thank you! Now its working.

But now i have another problem, it not print output1, only 2? Why is that?

Both text files have same amount of lines.

Comment: @TheExel80 I don't see how that is possible. If you include the content of the input files, and the output you're getting, I can take a look.